# Activating multiple versions of a page in AEM over time

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, scheduling, aem, activation

In AEM (Adobe Experience Manager), I'm trying to schedule the activation of multiple versions of a single page that have slightly different content each day. So, while I'm out-of-office on Saturday morning, the "Saturday" version of the page is auto-activated. Then on Sunday morning, the "Sunday" version of the page is activated. On Monday morning, the "Monday" version of the page is activated, and so on. So far, I've only been able to successfully schedule a single change, not multiple changes over time, as described. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Came across this: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/launches.html but haven't had a chance to really go through it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to directly do activation of different versions at different times, but an alternative you could consider would be to create the portion(s) of the the page you to change over time as a teaser component, then use segmentation to define time-based segments that would cause the page to render those portions differently depending on the date/time.

Check out this documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/personalization/campaigns/segmentation.html.  It states

> "...segments are then used to provide a visitor with specifically
>   targeted content."

This wouldn't be a typical usage of segmentation, but it is a way to accomplish what you want to do.  In step 6, when creating a new segment, you would need to define a JavaScript expression that evaluates the date/time to resolve the segment to true/false. You could define several such segments for each date/time you need, then depending on which segment resolves to true different content would be shown.

This has overview info https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/personalization/campaigns.html and says that

> "Typically a teaser page is a temporary action that will last for a
>   specific period of time, until it is replaced by the next teaser
>   page."

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions, I will give it a try. That being said, shouldn't the scheduling of content, in the way I describe, be "table stakes" for a professional CMS like AEM. Kind of shocking that the process is this complicated. But thanks again, I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  What I mentioned is one way to perhaps do what you want, but I admit it seems like overkill.  It may very well just be that I don't know how to do what you want in a simpler way--so perhaps others will chime in with better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

At least from AEM 6.3 (I didn't check the earlier versions, but quite sure it works the same way) there is "Scheduled publication" function.
When you schedule the page for activation the snapshot version is created and that very version will be published, even if the page itself was changed since then. And this can be used for several times. So actually you have what you need works out-of-the-box.
I would suggest you to investigate `/etc/workflow/models/scheduled_activation/jcr:content/`
for more information.